# ngSanitize Removes Relative IMG

Tags: angularjs

Why does ngSanitize remove image sources with relative path, like `<img src="/img/lol.jpg>`
from html text, but it does not touch images with absolute path like `<img src="http://site.com/img/lol.jpg">`?

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle with a demo?

Comment: Reproduce scenario here: http://plnkr.co/edit/b4AhqPpNp2NvMLmt67Jd?p=preview (check the console). IMO it deserves a replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [image URL whitelist](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b7e82a33eee03fc683f982c6ee13d15d88b07f67/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js) regexp is `/^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\/)/` which does not match relative URLs.

You can overwrite the white list as per [the compile provider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#!).

```
app.config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(<your regexp here>);
});
```